# Get layout name in front end - fluid typo3

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid-layout, extbase

I have a fluid typo3 site with single page layout.One menu have different layout.How to get the selected layout name in my main template?

**main.html**

```
 <v:page.menu levels="1" as="sections">
                    <f:for each="{sections}" as="section" iteration="itemIteration">

     <f:debug>{sections}</f:debug>
    </f:for>
                </v:page.menu>
```

sub.html

```
<f:layout name="Pagewithnav" />
    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="subnav" icon="{f:uri.resource(path: 'Icons/Page/logo.png')}" label="Sub Navigation">
            <!-- Insert fields, sheets, grid, form section objects etc. here, in this flux:form tag -->
        </flux:form>
        <flux:grid>
            <!-- Edit this grid to change the "backend layout" structure -->
            <flux:grid.row>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="0" colspan="4" name="main" label="Navigation wrapper" />
            </flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.row>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="1" colspan="4" name="main" label="Main wrapper" />
            </flux:grid.row>
        </flux:grid>
    </f:section>
    <f:section name="Main">
        <div class="sub_nav">
           <div class="container">
               <v:content.render column="0"/>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <v:content.render column="1"/>
        </div>
    </f:section>
```

Comment: If you want the backend layout of a page, in normal case you can obtain it from $GLOBALS['TSFE'] array.
But here it is about Flux,right ?? But inside a template provider extension is there a need to know the backend layout picked.? Please explain you requirement more precisely.

Comment: @AnuBhuvanendranNair I need the template name in fluid flux template.Since im using provider extension i cant use $GLOBALS['TSFE'] array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "Layout name":

- If you mean fields of the `pages` table for each individual page then those will be available in each record when you iterate it in `v:page.menu` (for example, `tx_fed_page_controller_action`).
- If you mean fields of `pages` but also when this variable is inherited (for example, `backend_layout` is and `tx_fed_page_controller_action` is as well, but each through different methods) it becomes more complex: you would need to walk through the root line and use the first non-empty value. For that, `v:page.rootLine` plus `v:iterator.filter` plus `v:iterator.first` can be of great help (put output from root line into filter to remove non-empty values then use the `first` VH to select the first value from that filtered result).
- If you define this "layout" in a Flux form field on your page template it becomes a FlexForm variable which you can read with `flux:form.data` (with inheritance if not disabled and if templates match up through root line).

Depending on exactly which you mean there are quite a few possible solutions. If you are also looking for a recommendation about which one it makes sense to use: most likely you mean the layout you select in page properties (regardless of field) and for this, `v:page.rootLine` plus `v:iterator.filter` plus `v:iterator.first` is a nice and generic method to "slide select" any non-empty value from the root line of the current page.

Comment: I got  tx_fed_page_controller_action from {_all.sections} .Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with a variable in fluid

```
lib.templateName = TEXT
lib.templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
lib.templateName.stdWrap {
    cObject = TEXT
    cObject {
        data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
        override.field = backend_layout
        split {
            token = pagets__
            1.current = 1
            1.wrap = |
        }
    }
    ifEmpty = Default
}

page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    #...
    variables.templateName < lib.templateName
}
```

Comment: I tried this method.But didnt get the templatename. I tried <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.templateName" />

Comment: as you don't use it in page context the data object of the typoscript may vary. therefore you might need to get the page object from the data obejct first and then access the backend_layout fields.